# Issue with validation on Kendo-Grid

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this code with me..

```
$ dataBound: function () {
            dataView = this.dataSource.view();

            $("#amount_detail tbody tr .k-grid-ChequeDetails").each(function () {
                var currentDataItem1 = $("#amount_detail").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
                if (currentDataItem1.cheque_status == "0") {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
```

but problem is, i want to make validation on button using data from another table.

I want to show button in grid using data from another table. Eg: if table "B.eu_id = 1" show Edit button in "A Grid" else hide that button

Comment: Demonstrate your case

Comment: I am showing table A in grid format, but having validation on some records which is connecting to table B, how can i give validation on that some records